# Best way to structure class with "getRepository()" - Typeorm w/ Type-Graphql

Tags: typeorm, typegraphql

Currently in all of my resolvers, I type and construct the required repositories as so:

```
export class UserResolver {
  userRepo: Repository<User>;

  constructor() {
    this.userRepo = getRepository(User);
  }
  ...
```

Is this bad practice / is there a better way to structure my resolvers / classes?

Comment: That depends on the DI library you use. TypeDI has some helpers like `@InjectRepository`, I believe you can write similar stuff for tsyringe or inversify-js.

Comment: I still inject my repositories using the constructor. It's fine for me...